# How to convert CLOB to String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, ajax, h2

I've inserted images on H2 database as base64 encoded format as images has very small size (i.e. icons < 5KB).

I've used CLOB datatype for this and its storing it properly in "img" column.

i.e.

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAIAAAACUFjqAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAACtSURBVChTVY8LEsIgDES5qybY6SHKp3oKsR5CqxezJdA6pqT+ZnaGhEc2i4o0i8aYrPXhdI6UP5dfTJQR0RjDeEg/eEh5jBPfgsbGGq7/MNtKAwBlemUsZYzjIcQdS2tA3ALwsUNdHUOnQuhc653fe+8BNnVdte2BW9bleiu7RxKrEs2VHLIxK24oPQVrrZvGFrYk5WLB74+uybl+0GLAY5Jc3CbO0ff38rSI5hdpMe9eZGPCOAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

The issue is while doing `select *`, it shows:

> "clob19: SPACE(398 /* table: 4875 id: 1 */)"

instead of actual string which I've mentioned. And I'm calling this `SELECT *` from jquery/ajax (not Java) so ajax response in json showing like this:

```
[{"img":"clob19: SPACE(398 \/* table: 4875 id: 1 *\/)","type":"abc","id":"1"}]
```

How can I convert img data to string to get my base64 text?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with hsqldb which is like h2's sister.

I choosed the easy way the resolve the problem by using a longvarchar datatype instead of a clob in order to use text data instead of binary data.

The performance was good with  more than 10^6 rows

In H2, Integer = ] -2147483648 ; 2147483647[ so I imagine you can store at least 2gb of data in a text field

Comment: thanks but There is no longvarchar in h2... see http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html

Comment: http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#varchar_type
Just try " Integer.MAX_VALUE" to see the varchar size limit

Comment: varchar has limit of 255 and my base64 binary string is much more than that

Comment: like this: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAIAAAACUFjqAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAACtSURBVChTVY8LEsIgDES5qybY6SHKp3oKsR5CqxezJdA6pqT+ZnaGhEc2i4o0i8aYrPXhdI6UP5dfTJQR0RjDeEg/eEh5jBPfgsbGGq7/MNtKAwBlemUsZYzjIcQdS2tA3ALwsUNdHUOnQuhc653fe+8BNnVdte2BW9bleiu7RxKrEs2VHLIxK24oPQVrrZvGFrYk5WLB74+uybl+0GLAY5Jc3CbO0ff38rSI5hdpMe9eZGPCOAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`

Comment: Are you sure of that , the doc says "The maximum precision is Integer.MAX_VALUE. The precision is a size constraint; only the actual data is persisted." ?

Comment: Sorry..I didn't get that.. Is this mean I can store character more than 255

Comment: I suppose, you should be able to have a field with a  length of Integer.MaxValue

Comment: So do you mean I should use `varchar` datatype?

Comment: VARCHAR should be used for text with relatively short average size (for example shorter than 200 characters).

Comment: If you want to do it the easy way, I would say yes. However the data will be loaded in memory. So if you have 1gb of pictures, it will consumme 1GB of memory when running the DB. This is the drawback. With a BLOB field the data is only on the drive an accessed on demand, which saves RAM usage

Comment: Yes. I tried that and it's working and showing proper result. But need still need proper way to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for helping

Comment: You where saying that you a are trying to store small images like icons << 5kb. By using a blob or a clob, you will do a lot of disk access, and maybe loosing the interest of fast serving data. For exemple, if you are thinking of using your database to provide pictures of a web site, it could be faster to answer a lot of queries with a text field than a blob field. By choosing a blob field, you mightnot benefit of the db caching mechnism and thoose of the web server (it would keep in cache the http queries to provide pictures)... I have no mesures but it could be somthing to consider